# Why does my Facebook app isn't loading pages?

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-apps

I'm making an app on Facebook using WordPress and everything is fine, I'm on the front page of the app, but when I try to access a link to another page of my app in Mozilla Firefox shows a blank page and in Google Chrome stays on the front page.

Has anyone an idea of why this is happening? Has anyone encountered this behaviour?

My next code is used by me in the WordPress root index.php, not the front page index.php, to request permissions of the user before entering the app:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Front to the WordPress application. This file doesn't do anything, but loads
 * wp-blog-header.php which does and tells WordPress to load the theme.
 *
 * @package WordPress
 */

/**
 * Tells WordPress to load the WordPress theme and output it.
 *
 * @var bool
 */

session_start();
require 'src/facebook.php';

//  LOGIN
$app_details = array('app_id' => 'secret',
                     'app_secret' => 'secret',
                     'page_link' => '//www.facebook.com/secret/'
                     );
$http = "http:";
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) 
    if (!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) $http = "https:";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_details['app_id'], 
  'secret' => $app_details['app_secret'],
  'cookie' => true 
));

$the_signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
if ($the_signed_request == null) {
    header("Location: ".$http.$app_details['page_link']."app/".$app_details['app_id']);
}

if ( !isset($the_signed_request['user_id']) && !isset($the_signed_request['oauth_token']) ){
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'email')); 
   if (!isset($_SESSION['rejects'])) $_SESSION['refuzuri'] = 0;
        else $_SESSION['rejects']++;
    if ($_SESSION['rejects']>4) {
        echo "This app works only if permissions are accepted.<br/>";
        echo "To accept the permissions <a href='".$loginUrl."' target='_top'>click here</a>";
        die();
    } 
    echo( "<script>top.location.href='" . $loginUrl . "';</script>" );
}else{
     try{
        $access_token = $facebook->getAccessToken();
        $user = $facebook->getUser();//userid
         $userinfo = $facebook->api('/me?fields=id,name,email,gender,locale'); //for basic details

    }catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
     $user = null;
     $userinfo = null;         
    }
    $_SESSION['user']= $userinfo;
        define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);

        /** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
        require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );

}
?>
```

Comment: @YuriBlanc,  no, I'm not.

Comment: Can you may add more details in order to help you. Some code & snapshots?

Comment: @YuriBlanc, scratch my last comment. I had 'https' in my php code. I will provide my code in my question imeadiatelly. Maybe will help determine what am I doing wrong.

Comment: @YuriBlanc, added the code.

Comment: You add data to session but you load WP only when you set the session. So perhaps  require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' ); should go off the else condition or when is already set it won't load wp-blog-header.php

Comment: @YuriBlanc, I've put the require( dirname( FILE ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' ); after I set the session and now the pages are showing but I get a warning "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by". Also the permission request is not working as I want anymore. The catch was that the user can't enter the app if he didn't accepted the permissions request. Now he can do that without accept the permissions.

Comment: Ok but what you do when the permissions are set and the session data is present?

Comment: What do you mean? I need user info's in my session because I'm using them in the app.